# using FFMPEG to crop video but only audio is produced

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this command to crop a few seconds of mkv/mp4 videos. Sometimes it works perfectly fine.
But other times the output file which is in mp4 format only contains the audio. How can I fix it?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 01:10:15 -to 01:10:20 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `-c:v copy -c:a copy` Re-encode it.

Direct stream copy copies the GOP (Group of pictures) chunks of the structure of file (from the first I-frame to the last P or B-frame).
Presumably your time is too short, less than one chunk of GOP.

Comment: but re-encoding would take much more time. is there a better solution? like finding the nearest I-frame?

Comment: "like finding the nearest I-frame?" Low accuracy of search. Approx time. Look there https://superuser.com/questions/554620/how-to-get-time-stamp-of-closest-keyframe-before-a-given-timestamp-with-ffmpeg